# AJAX function is working and throwing "Uncaught ReferenceError" at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following `is_logged_in()` function resolves exactly as intended. However at the same time it also throws this error to console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: is_logged_in is not defined

There is no ReferenceError when the function is called outside of `$('.favorite-btn').on('click', function() ...`

```
function is_logged_in() {
    $.ajax({
        url: cml_theme.ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'is_logged_in'
        },
        success: function(result) {
            if ( result == 'yes' ) {
                console.log('yep');
            } else {
                console.log('nope');
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('is_logged_in() AJAX call error');
        }
    });
};

$('.favorite-btn').on('click', function() {
    is_logged_in(); // logs 'yep' or 'nope' to console
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Wrapping docuemnt.ready around these functions doesn't resolve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @Nick - if you remove the whole $.ajax code, does the error persist? Also, does the stack trace for the error help pinpoint the cause?

Comment: Stack trace showing issues with HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>, HTMLDivElement.dispatch and HTMLDivElement.q.handle all in jquery.min.js


Same error persists if I remove the entire $.ajax function

Comment: which version of jQuery - and have you tried removing the $.ajax altogether

Comment: @JaromandaX hah! my bad. To be honest, nothing about this question makes sense given the code sample and error mesage

Comment: Removing $.ajax altogether throws the same error. Using is_loged_in() inside the on.('click', function() {...}) is causing a problem. Never experienced before...

Comment: your **posted** code (without the ajax) https://jsfiddle.net/kx605hk6/ works fine ...

Comment: there must be some conflict somewhere; although this is one of the only functions I'm running... Very odd, thanks for your help

Comment: in your console, type `is_logged_in + ''` ... does the function look right?

Comment: is there a form, and what type of element is `favorite-btn`

Comment: you're right @RoryMcCrossan - it does look impossible! (but, javascript makes the impossible possible)

Comment: put that `console.log(is_logged_in + '')` before and after the call to `is_logged_in` ... and, for fun, inside the success callback :p - another question .. is the error shown before or after "yep/nope"

Comment: As a side note, you should try making a get request instead of a post. You can simplify your function by doing `$.get(cml_theme.ajaxurl + '?action=is_logged_in')` and from here you can expand on it. Maybe you can get rid of the error with this, note that in your backend you'll have to fetch the data from the get variable if you want to use this.

Comment: @AntoniuLivadariu - why? the server may expect only a POST :p

Comment: Just for convention, post is usually used when submitting data, if you ask for data you should use get. At the end of the day it doesn't matter though haha